# Regex getting two specific characters within square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Not too well-versed with Regex. I have a string like this:

```
 var str = "WOMEN~~Accessories >Underwear~~Socks, Tights & Leggings"
```

Using Javascript, I want to split at: `~~`, `&`, `>` and `,` including potential white space surrounding them.

So far I've got:

```
 var arr = str.split(/[\s>&,]/g);
 for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]){accepted.push(arr[i])}
 }
```

This doesn't account for multiple characters though (and I'm sure there's a better way to regex in the white space rather than a `for` loop after the fact!) and the `~~` isn't selected.

I'm thinking something along the lines of `/[\s>&,[~~]]/g` but this doesn't work. How can I do this with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\s*[\s>&,\[\]~]+\s*/g
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/p7FFD/

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = str.split(/(~~|[\s>&,]+)/g);
```

So you're splitting on either ~~ or any combination of whitespace, ampersands, greater than (>) and commas.

Comment: What does the `*` after the square brackets indicate?

Comment: @Jascination It indicates that the previous group must be present 0 or more times.

Comment: @Theox Which was actually _wrong_, as we want at least one of those characters. Thanks, I adjusted my answer.